# unable to use localdb and dacpac for integration tests on ci server

Tags: sql-server, powershell, continuous-integration, sql-server-data-tools

I have large project that uses SSDT DACPACs for database changes and migrations.
I am attempting to implement integration testing by deploying the entire schema to a localdb and running tests against this db.

I use the below powershell script to deploy the dac and the build server outputs reports the following:

```
LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" created with version 13.0.2151.0.
LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" started.
Name:               MSSQLLocalDB
Version:            13.0.2151.0
Shared name:        
Owner:              NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
...
Creating [tr_MStran_alterview]...
Update complete.
Updating database (Complete)
```

The database appears to be deployed. However the unit tests cannot connect to the database and I cannot see them in VS SQL Server Object Explorer (open as system account).

I believe it is configured correctly. I have the dacpac publish profile configured to target the following connection string `<TargetConnectionString>Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False</TargetConnectionString>`: `<TargetDatabaseName>somedatabase_integrationTest</TargetDatabaseName>`

I tested it on my local machine and it worked but I need it to work on the build server.
My test project is configured to connect to the following db:
`<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=somedatabase_integrationtest;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=300"/>`

All tasks are performed using bamboo which runs under the system account.

```
function setupLocalDB() {
    sqllocaldb info 
    sqllocaldb create mssqllocaldb
    sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb 
    sqllocaldb info mssqllocaldb
    $env:UserDomain
    $env:ComputerName
}
function publishDacFile($dacProfilePath, $dacPacFilePath) {
    #load DLL
    $dacLibPath = join-path $pwd Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x86.140.3652.3\lib\net40\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll
    Add-Type -path $dacLibPath
    #load Profile
    $dacProfile = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacProfile]::Load($dacProfilePath)
    $dacService = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices($dacProfile.TargetConnectionString)

    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $dacService -EventName "Message" -Action { Write-Host $EventArgs.Message.Message } | out-null

    $dacPublishOptions = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.PublishOptions
    $dacPublishOptions.DeployOptions = $dacProfile.DeployOptions
    $dacPublishOptions.GenerateDeploymentReport = $true
    $dacPublishOptions.GenerateDeploymentScript = $false
    # Load dacpac from file & deploy to database named publish

    $dacPac = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage]::Load($dacPacFilePath) 
    $publishResult = $dacService.Publish($dacPac, $dacProfile.TargetDatabaseName, $dacPublishOptions)
    $publishResult.DeploymentReport
}
```

How can I get the tests to see the localdb instance without messing around with user accounts or installing full blown SQL Server?

Comment: What executes your unit tests/what are they written in?

Comment: I use mstest to execute the integration tests.

Comment: so a couple of things - older versions of .net don't support localdb so you will need to make sure it isn't like .net 2 or something + instances are local to users - is it the same user who creates the instance as tries to connect to it? If it is a different user on the same machine then you can share the instance "sqllocaldb share". If the users are the same and .net recent version try turning tracing on and looking in the sql ERRORLOG for errors connecting

Comment: @EdElliott. Thanks for the advice. Both the tests and the creating the DB are run under the system account. I am also targeint .NET framework 4.5.2 so that shouldn't be an issue.